# Sitecore Redis engine version compatibility

Tags: session-state, redis

I'm planning on using Redis for shared and private session for my Sitecore 9 update 1 site. There is already an existing Redis cluster running using Redis version 4.0.10. I believe the Azure Redis cache service uses Redis 3.2.7.

Is there any issue using Redis 4.0.10 for session, if so what are the Redis versions that work with Sitecore 9 update 1?